# Ephemeral messages using Bot Composer

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

Any ideas on How to send "*ephemeral*" messages using Bot Framework Composer?

I am building a bot that "listens" in a shared channel and under certain circumstances, it should reply ONLY to a specific user. I know I could send a private message, but that will require the user to "get out" of the channel.

In Slack, it looks like this:

[image]

Ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a bug in the C# BotFramework SDK's Slack adapter that, at present, blocks ephemeral messages from working. You can reference this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/5602) that discusses the problem.

There is a workaround presented there, but it applies to the developer who is building his bot using the SDK. In your case, building from Composer, you could also clone the repo, make the necessary changes, and build the files locally. Then, you should be able to reference the updated library in the bot's runtime.

At this point, you ought to be able to construct an activity in Composer following the SDK's schema for a [NewSlackMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.adapters.slack.model.newslackmessage?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable).

Comment: I reported that bug in the SDK, and I am currently using that workaround... but I thought Composer would make my life easier and not keep a custom copy of that library :). Thank you for your help.